# Run jbehave stories from a user defined location

Tags: java, jbehave

I am new to jbehave

I am trying to execute jbehave through junit. It seems jbehave loads story files only from the classpath. Will it be possible to configure it to fetch story files from a user defined path.

```
public class AlgebraStory extends JUnitStories {  

@Override  
public Configuration configuration() {  
 return super.configuration()  
     .useStoryReporterBuilder(  
         new StoryReporterBuilder()  
             .withDefaultFormats()  
             .withFormats(CONSOLE, TXT));  
}  

@Override  
public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {  
  return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new Calculator());  
}  

@Override  
protected List<String> storyPaths() {  
  return new  StoryFinder().findPaths((<user defined path>, "**/algebra_story.story", "");  
  }  
}
```

In the same way will it be possible to save jbehave reports in user defined path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can locate your stories anywhere you want in the network. be them in class path, or externally, locatable via URLs. see [locating stories](http://jbehave.org/reference/latest/locating-stories.html).

And I recommend you to learn JBehave through its examples. as this [one](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/blob/master/examples/core/src/main/java/org/jbehave/examples/core/CoreStories.java). But in my own opinion the best way to setup an execution is using [Embedders](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/blob/master/examples/core/src/main/java/org/jbehave/examples/core/CoreEmbedder.java).